# Android - How to change the launch activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

How can I set an Activity that will be the Launch Activity just one time ( when the user sign up )?
e.g.
I have a Settings Activity and a NewsFeed Activity.
The first time I want to lanch the app with the Settings Activity and, after the user fill the options, he goes to the NewsFeed Activity.
The second time, after the settings filled, I want to launch the app with NewsFeed Activity.

I google it but could not find any detailed explanation or tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple.

You can use preferences to store if this first time then show Settings Activity else always show NewsFeed Activity.

Below is the sample code to use Preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPrefs", MODE_WORLD_0);
boolean settingsFilled = prefs.getBoolean("SettingsFilled", false);

if(!settingsFilled)
{
    //SHOW SETTINGS ACTIVITY

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPrefs", 0);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("SettingsFilled", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Use the above code in your NewsFeed Activity.

Comment: There is any tutorial where I can find how to use preferences in this case? They way I am think about the code I will have to declare the SharedPreferences and set that is first time in some place or not?
Do I need to change something in AndroidManifest.xml or NewsFeedActivity still will be my Launcher Activity there?

Comment: You don't need to change your AndroidManifest.xml. Keep NewsFeedActivity as your Launcher Activity and upon its launch check if the settings are filled or not. If settings are not filled then launch Settings Activity before showing the NewsFeed Activity. I will update my answer with code.:)

Comment: @user3249186: Code sample added.